# Adding lines when printing treeset

Tags: java, treeset

I have this simple treeset.

```
 TreeSet<Fruit> treeSet = new TreeSet();
    try {
        treeSet.add(pear);
        treeSet.add(apple);
        treeSet.add(orange);
        System.out.println(treeSet);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

when this compiles it prints it all out on the same line. How can i make it so it prints each object out on a different line?

Comment: it's better to use `TreeSet<Fruit> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();` rather than `TreeSet<Fruit> treeSet = new TreeSet();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print it in a loop

```
for(Fruit f: treeSet){
    System.out.println(f);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the `Set` and print each element separatelly:

```
TreeSet<Fruit> treeSet = new TreeSet();
treeSet.add(pear);
treeSet.add(apple);
treeSet.add(orange);
for (Fruit fruit : treeSet) {
    System.out.println(fruit);
}
```

or (Java 8):

```
treeSet.forEach(System.out::println);
```